# setResizable(false) doesn't prevent the frame to restore down after double click

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Even the Restore down button in the title bar is disabled the user can still get the same behavior by double click on the title bar.

```
this.setResizable(false);
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

I'm using Java 11 on Windows 10 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mention the "Restore Down" button you mean following icon in a window's *title bar*:

[image: window title bar: "Restore Down" button in Windows]

The [`setResizable(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable(boolean)) method on a `JFrame` simply enables or disables the user to resize it.
This means hovering with the mouse over the window's corners will either show or not show a double-headed *resize-cursor* like this:

[image: cursor shown when resize allowed]

#### Show the window maximized and disable resizing

The order of settings is important.

```java
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);
```

See also:

- [setResizable()](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap62/ch62_2.html)
- [Java how to make JFrames maximised but not resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882417/java-how-to-make-jframes-maximised-but-not-resizable)